# Objective - C - push NSArray with performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this block of code here:

```
if(isLocationTag == YES)
    {
        NSArray *isLocationTagArray = [self getLocationInfo:Name];

        if(isLocationTagArray == nil)
        {

            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"There is an issue with the location tag." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
            [alertController addAction:ok];

            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

            ScannerMessage.text = @"READY TO SCAN";
            ScannerMessage.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        }
        else
        {
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueIdentifier" sender: self];
        }
    }
```

and what I am trying to do is push the NSArray isLocationTagArray with the `performSegueWithIdentifier`

I have added this method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier"])
    {
        ListViewController *myVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    }

}
```

But how do I pass the NSArray ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a property in your destination VC (ListViewController) then set it in the prepareForSegue. Something like this:

ListViewController.h

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray* theParamenterArray;
```

then in your prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier"])
    {
        ListViewController *myVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        myVC.theParamenterArray = isLocationTagArray;
    }
}
```

This's the standard way for all the data you want to exchange between VCs using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Make `isLocationTagArray` a module level variable. Then add a property to your `ListViewController` that can accept the `NSArray`

Then you can do this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier"])
    {
        ListViewController *myVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        myVC.dataArray = isLocationTagArray
    }

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass your `NSArray` as sender:

```
...
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueIdentifier" sender: isLocationTagArray];
...
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueIdentifier"]) {
        ListViewController *myVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        if ([sender isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]]) {
            myVC.dataArray = (NSArray *) sender;
        }
    }

 }
```